# Do totally Chlorine free (TCF) toilet papers exist?

Tags: paper, manufacturing, toilet

Many [online resources](https://thegreentoilet.blogspot.de/2008/02/so-why-is-toilet-paper-white-anyway.html) suggest that processed Chlorine free (PCF) and TCF toilet papers are more environmentally friendly than elemental Chlorine free (ECF) toilet papers. Although I can find a lot of actually existing PCF products, I couldn't find any actual TCF toilet papers. Do they really exist in reality?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! PCF = TCF + recycled content, so any product classified as PCF is also TCF. Or are you looking for TCF paper which isn't PCF?

Comment: @THelper Thanks for your answer. Can you give a source for the information? I wasn't aware of that fact. And yes, it's also good to know whether pure TCF exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table on [this Conservatree.org webpage](http://www.conservatree.org/paper/PaperTypes/CFDisc.shtml) explains that Processed Chlorine Free (PCF) means it's Totally Chlorine Free (TCF) plus it has recycled content. So all the PCF papers you found are also TCF.

Conservatree.org also has [listings](http://www.conservatree.org/paper/PaperMasterList.shtml) for recycled and PCF paper products, including [this relatively large list of toilet paper for consumer usage](http://www.conservatree.org/paper/PaperGuide/Tissue/consumerbath.shtml) (US and Canada oriented). I'm not aware of any toilet paper that is TCF and not PCF.